# Counting with Lua in tabularx (but not tabular) is three times as much as it should be

Tags: latex

Counting the number of rows with a Lua variable in a tabularx environment always gives me a multiple of what it should be:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewEnviron{funds}{%
    \directlua{rows = 0}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{ |X|c| }
     \BODY
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand\fundsadd{%
    \directlua{rows = rows + 1}
    a & b \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{funds}
    \fundsadd
    \fundsadd
    \fundsadd
\end{funds}

Number of rows: \directlua{tex.sprint{rows}}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: rendered output]

but the number of rows should be 3. It works fine in a tabular environment. Is there anything about tabularx that I am missing?

Comment: tabularx needs to process the content several times to measure the required space and  determine the best width of the columns.

Comment: tex counters would work out of the box: https://pastebin.com/iaWdtXhS

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I feared this is happening. Interestingly, this is not happening if one uses standard counters.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, that's right, counters work. But in my actual problem I am using the Lua variables to track different expenses and working with Lua variables makes the whole code much more flexible.

Comment: TeX is Turing complete, flexibility is only a function of your determination :)

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at `datatool` instead if reinventing the wheel ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabularx` needs to process the content several time. You can work around the problem by resetting your counter at the start of the tabularx instead of before.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\NewEnviron{funds}{%    
    \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{ |X|c| }
        \directlua{rows = 0}
        \BODY
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand\fundsadd{%
    \directlua{rows = rows + 1}
    a & b \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{funds}
    \fundsadd
    \fundsadd
    \fundsadd
\end{funds}

Number of rows: \directlua{tex.sprint{rows}}

\end{document}
```